# How to center a fixed sized view in a ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I've got a very basic issue on Android I've been struggling with the past few hours.
I can't make a `ViewPager` view content center in it's container. Here is my code:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#FF0000FF">

    ...

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

so the view appears correctly in my `ViewPager` but it just doesn't center. By setting a color on the `FrameLayout`, it appears that it wraps the `LinearLayout` instead of doing a mach parent. I tried with a `RelativeLayout` and also a `LinearLayout` with no much chance, any idea?

Comment: Have you tried using android:gravity="center"?

Comment: on the viewpager? yeah it didn't do anything

Comment: why do you need frameLayout as the outer layout? why don't you use a linearLayout or a RelativeLayout? it would center easy inside them

Comment: before i didn't have any but I got the same result. the issue there is that the layout_gravity attribute doesn't do anything

Comment: Did you do any operation with LayoutParams on LinearLayout components in your code (i don't know if there are other things in your LinearLayout)?

Comment: yeah there are other things but I haven't done any changes and it's still doesn't fill the screen. Setting the layout params of the framelayout programmatically is working though. I'm wondering why the match parent doesn't want to operate

Comment: How did you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#FF0000FF">

    ...

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Try this

Comment: same result, it doesn't make much difference centerInParent would only help if the view parent was a relativelayout

Comment: I know, that is what I wanted to post, it seems there was an error when I posted, I don't know why the relative layout wasn't showing, this is what I posted